# Python ibm pyomo cplex

Tags: python, linux, cplex, pyomo, websphere

I need some help with the activation of cplex community edition on linux in combination with python/pyomo. I have followed the installation procedure on https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/297247

I have written the following two lines into my bash_profile

```
export CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR1210=/path/to/cplex

export CPLEX_API_KEY=...
```

Then I have restarted my machine but I always get the message "Cplex Error 1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded."

I also have tried to write the export lines into bashrc but without success.

My relevant python code line looks like: 
    Optimize = SolverFactory ('cplex', executable='/path/to/cplex-executable')

I am looking forward to any hints. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unlock the model size limitations you need to set the `CPLEX_STUDIO_KEY` environment variable, **not** `CPLEX_API_KEY`. If you fix that, hopefully your issue should go away.

**EDIT:**

I didn't notice it the first time, but as far as I know, the CPLEX Community Edition is only available for 12.9 at this time. Please try setting the `CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR129` environment variable instead of `CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR1210`. For example:

```
export CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR129=/path/to/cplex
```

Comment: Thx I have changed it but the problem still exists. The exact error massage is: "CPLEX No binary directory found" and then CPLEX  Error 1016: community edition. Problem size limits exceeded.

Comment: The Edit did the job. 12.9 works. Sp finaöly realy easy but here you have to look into the details :) thx

Answer (score -1):

if you use the free community edition, the error

"Cplex Error 1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded."

is normal and means your model is bigger than what that free edition allows.

So you could either:

- Move to CPLEX academic initiative which is [free](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/blog/2019/07/04/cplex-optimization-studio-for-students-and-academics/) for academics
- Move to full [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer)
- Call CPLEX in the IBM cloud as a service ([WML](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/decision-optimization-now-available-in-watson-machine-learning-750f9752c2bc))